# Travel internationally while Australia visitor visa application pending?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, australia, e-visas

Indian passport holder working in USA here.

I have business meetings in Australia in January. I will apply for an Australia business visitor visa in USA.

It looks like it is an electronic application and I will not need to submit my original passport. Great news because I have personal international travel plans later this month for the holidays that I will need my passport for. But before I jump into my holiday travel: is it OK to travel internationally while my Australia visa application is under consideration in USA?

Any advice? Anyone done the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fine, provided you keep your passport. Australia no longer stamps visas into passports; they are all electronic now. So when you are approved for a visa, you don't need to take your passport to the consulate for stamping either.